# How do you define the Cosmos DB database and collection names when using the imperative bindings in a precompiled C# Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, binding, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

How do you define the Cosmos DB database and collection names when using the imperative bindings in a precompiled C# Azure Function?

I've followed the `run.csx` C# script example [Store unstructured data using Azure Functions and Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-integrate-store-unstructured-data-cosmosdb) and it works fine.

Trying to do similar with a precompiled C# function, and noticed that the generated `function.json` is missing the database and collection names.

Got the method attributed with the `DocumentDB` ...

```
[HttpTrigger(
  AuthorizationLevel.Function, 
  "get", "post", 
  Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
[DocumentDB(
  ConnectionStringSetting = "cflogdev_DOCUMENTDB", 
  CreateIfNotExists = true,
  PartitionKey = "user" )] out object logDocument,
ILogger log)
```

But Intellisense doesn't have the database and collection as settable values, however it did have an overload with them ...

I've checked the [DocumentDBAttribute](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB/DocumentDBAttribute.cs) 
and it has them as part of second constructor.

But how can you set them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it ...

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
  [DocumentDB(
        "logDatabase",
        "logCollection",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "cflogdev_DOCUMENTDB",
        //PartitionKey = "user",
        CreateIfNotExists = true
    )] out object logDocument,
  ILogger log)
```

I'm using version 1.0.0 of the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB`

Answer (score 0):

`DocumentDBAttribute(databaseName, collectionName)` constructor is available in the version that I use (`1.1.0-beta1`). Those properties are read-only, so you can't set them from the default constructor.